# ODE $d^2y/dx^2 + y/a^2 = u(x)$

Tags: integration, analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, partial-differential-equations

Does the following ODE:

$$d^2y/dx^2 + y/a^2 = u(x)$$

have a solution? where $u(x)$ is the step function and a is constant.

Comment: You should be able to solve it in two different domains and then try to meet continuity conditions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your source term, $u(x)$, is a piecewise continous function in $x \in \mathbb{R}$ and is therefore integrable. Since the particular solution of your ODE can be computed as (check it*):

$$y_p(x) = \frac{1}{y_1} \iint  u \, y_1   \, \mathrm{d}x^2 = y_1 \int \frac{1}{y^2_1}\left[ \underbrace{\int u y_1 \, \mathrm{d}x}_{=Y_1u(x)} \right] \, \mathrm{d}x, \tag{1}$$  where $y_1$ is one of the two fundamental solutions of the homogenous part of the ODE and $Y_1$ a primitive, I would say that this integral exists, since $u \, y_1$ is an integrable function over $x$.

**SPOILER**:

> The solution is given by:
>
> $$\color{blue}{y(x) = A_1 \sin{x/a} + A_2 \cos{x/a} + y_p(x) } \tag{2}$$
>
> Furthermore, note that none of this is necessary since the non-homogeneous term is a constant given by $u(x) = 1$ if $x>0$ and $u(x) = 0$ otherwise. If we suppose that $y_p(x) = C$ and substitute back in the ODE, we would have:
>
> $$\color{blue}{C = \left\{ \begin{array}{ll}
> 0   & \text{if } x < 0 \\
> a^2 & \text{if } x > 0
> \end{array} \right.}
> $$ or, equivalently, $\color{blue}{y_p(x) = a^2 u(x)}$.

**Edit:**

This solution is obtained via the method of variation of parameters (you can see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/652362/find-the-form-of-a-second-linear-independent-solution-when-the-two-roots-of-indi/652468#652468) an example) as follows:

- Let $y_1(x) = \sin{x/a}$ and $y_2(x) = \cos{x/a}$ be the solutions of the homogenous part of the equation $\mathcal{L}[y_h] = y''_h+ y_h/a^2 = 0$.
- Assume the complete solution is of the form $y(x) = A(x) y_1$, thus $y'' = A'' y_1 + 2 A'y'_1 + A y_1''$ and hence, substituting back in the ODE $\mathcal{L}[y] = u(x)$ we have, after dividing by $y_1 \neq 0$:
  $$ A'' + A' \frac{2 y_1'}{y_1} + A \frac{1}{y_1}\underbrace{(y_1''  + y_1/a^2 )}_{= \mathcal{L}[y_1] = 0} = \frac{u}{y_1} $$
- Note that we have a first order linear differential equation for $A'$ which we can solve using an integrating factor (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/658961/solve-the-following-differential-equation-ty-2y-sint/658963#658963)), $I(x) = \exp{\int 2y'_1 \, \mathrm{d}x /y_1}$:
  $$\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x} \left(y_1^2 \, A'  \right) = u y_1, $$
  so:
  $$A' = \frac{1}{y_1^2} \int u\, y_1 \, \mathrm{d}x + \frac{A_2}{y_1^2}, \tag{3}$$ with $A_2$ a constant of integration. This yields to:
  $$ A = \int{ \left[ \frac{1}{y_1^2} \int u\, y_1 \, \mathrm{d}x \right]  }\, \mathrm{d}x  + A_2 \int \frac{\mathrm{d}x}{y_1^2} + A_1,$$ with $A_1$ the other constant of integration. This yields to the final solution, $y(x)$, given by eq. (2) after further substitution and simplification.

Note that this method *always* works for linear ODEs for which you know at least one of the homogenous solutions, no matter their coefficients are constant or not. It's a nice exercise to show what the general solution of the ODE $y''(x) + p(x) y'(x) + q(x) y(x) = f(x)$ would be if we know that $y_1(x)$ and $y_2(x)$ satisfiy the homogenous ODE (it's a slightly different from what we have done here).

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, I don't completely understand the integral: Why it is dx^2?

Comment: It means $\mathrm{d}x \mathrm{d} x$ (it's a double indefinite integral).

Comment: Could you write the integral in extended form. If we integrate u y1 over x one time then the result would be independent of x. You mean integration from 0 to x 2 times?

Comment: See the edit and note that the result of the (indefinite) integration is still a function of $x$. Cheers!

Comment: A question: Assuming your solution, How about x=0 where the second derivative of u(x) would be infinity and the equation doesn't satisfy?

Comment: You can then use the following trick: solve the ode for the two regions in which the Heaviside function splits the domain. You will end up with 4 constants of integration. You can then put some of them as a function of the remaining imposing continuity of $y$ and $y'$ at $x=0$. I will let you to discuss if the  resulting solution has a continuous second derivative. Just for curiosity, has your problem any physical background? Is it an initial value problem?

Comment: The physics of problem is related to some kind of Poisson equation.

Comment: Could you let me know is there a theorem for $y_p(x) = integral$ or something that I can refer to or cite during the proof.

Comment: I mean for $y_p(x) = \frac{1}{y_1} \iint  u \, y_1   \, \mathrm{d}x^2 = \frac{1}{y_1} \int \left[ \underbrace{\int u y_1 \, \mathrm{d}x}_{=Y_1u(x)} \right] \, \mathrm{d}x$

Comment: Hi there again @Hesam, this is obtained via the method of variation of parameters. I will edit my answer later to show you how this was derived.

Comment: Many thanks, I need that.

Comment: You're welcome. See my edit. I also fixed an error in eq.(1).

Comment: Thanks, just a question: actually $a$ is imaginary constant. So instead of sin, I have exponential. However, I can not calculate $y_p$ from your new equation.

Comment: No matter what that value of $a$ is, provided you know the two functions $y_1$ and $y_2$. This method provides $y_p(x)$ as a function of the homogenous solutions, no matter their shape.

Comment: ... Then, it is worth remarking that: $(p+ \mathrm{i} \, q )^\alpha = \exp{\left( \alpha( \log{\sqrt{p^2+q^2}} + \mathrm{i} \, \arctan{q/p}) \right) }$. Cheers!

Comment: Could you guide me what happens if we had the step function in 2 places $d^2y/dx^2 + y/a^2 H(x) = H(-x)$

Comment: Sure!  I will be here in 2  hours approx.

Comment: Hi @Hesam, I answered your question. Forgive me for the delay. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/895420/solution-of-fracd2ydx2-frachx-yb-h-x/897628#897628