# Solution of $\frac{d^2y}{dx^2} - \frac{H(x) y}{b} = H(-x)$

Tags: integration, analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative

Does the equation

$$\frac{d^2y}{dx^2} - \frac{H(x)}{b} y = c H(x)$$

have a solution where $H(x)$ is the Heaviside step function and $b$ and $c$ are constant?

---

**Update: What about the second step function be $H(-x)$:**
$$\frac{d^2y}{dx^2} - \frac{H(x)}{b} y = c H(-x)$$

Comment: Solve the equation for $x>0$ and $x<0$ seperately and match the solution at $x=0$.

Comment: The answer to your question is yes. For example if $y(0)=y'(0)=0$ and $b=1$ you can easily check that $y(x) = (\cosh(x)-1)H(x)$ is a solution. To find the general solution just follow the steps above.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For $x<0$, $y''=0$, i.e. $$y=C_1x+C_0.$$

For $x\ge0$, $y''-\frac1by=1$.

Assuming $b>0$, the solution of the homogenous equation is
$$y=A\exp(\frac x{\sqrt b})+B\exp(-\frac x{\sqrt b}),$$
and a particular solution is
$$y=-b.$$
Hence the general solution,
$$y=A\exp(\frac x{\sqrt b})+B\exp(-\frac x{\sqrt b})-b.$$

You will ensure continuity of the function by equating the function and first derivative at $x=0$:
$$C_0=A+B-b\\C_1=\frac A{\sqrt b}-\frac B{\sqrt b}.$$

In particular, starting from the steady state, $A=B=\frac b2$, and
$$y=b\left(\cosh(\frac x{\sqrt b})-1\right)H(x).$$

Comment: Thanks, but the second derivative of H(x) f(x) wouldn't have continuity and would have Kroeniker delta in it.

Comment: @Hesam: $y''$ must be discontinuous (unless $y(0)=-b$), that's obvious. But there is no $\delta$.

Comment: What if second $H(x)$ be $H(-x)$. I thought maybe it becomes $cosh(-x)$ but it is same as $cosh(x)$

Answer (score 3):

I'm going to answer the updated question, which asks for the solution of the problem:

> $$ \color{green}{y''(x) - \frac{H(x)}{b} y(x) = H(-x) \, c } \tag{1}$$

which can be rewritten equivalently as follows:

$$ \begin{array}{ll}
y_1'' - \frac{1}{b} y_1 = 0 & \quad x > 0  \\ \tag{2}
y_2'' = c & \quad x < 0  
\end{array}$$

where I have denoted $y_1(x)$ as the solution for $x>0$ and $y_2(x)$ the solution for $x<0$. If we integrate both equations we will arrive at:

> $$ \color{blue}{y_1(x) = A e^{r_1 x} + B e^{r_2 x}, \quad y_2(x) = \frac{c x^2}{2} + Dx +E} \tag{3}$$

where $r_i$ are the solutions of the characteristic equation $s^2 - 1/b = 0$ and $A, B,  D$ and $E$ are constants of integration. To enforce continuity of both the function and its first derivative, we must provide:

$$y_1(0) = y_2(0), \quad y'_1(0) = y_2'(0), \tag{4}$$

which yields to:

\begin{align}
A+B & = E  \\
Ar_1 + B r_2 & = D, \tag{5}
\end{align} which gives us the solution, provided $r_1 \neq r_2$:

> $$\color{blue}{A = \frac{D-r_2 E}{r_1 - r_2} , \quad B = \frac{D - r_1 E}{r_2 - r_1}}  \tag{6}$$

The constants $D$ and $E$ remain unkown until any boundary conditions or initial conditions are specified.

Hope this helps!

Cheers.

Comment: Thanks, Isn't it possible to have $xe^{-x}$ in the solution due to the jump at $x=0$?

Comment: I'm not sure about what you mean with "to have $xe^{ -x}$ in the solution". What are the values of $b$? What is your domain? Is this an IVP or a BVP? As I told you once, it should be extremely helpful for us to help you better that you give us some more detailed description of (the physical meaning of) your problem.

Comment: I mean that with your previous answer about $y_p(x)$, considering $y_1(x)=exp(x)$ I could get  $y_p(x) = x e^{-x}$. However, I am wondering if we can have that term too or not.

Comment: I don't remember too much of my questions :)... but notice that the particular solutions of this problems are rather easy to obtain.

Comment: I mean this link: math.stackexchange.com/questions/895420/solution-of-fracd2ydx2-frachx-yb-h-x/897628?noredirect=1#comment1852684_897628

Comment: uhmm... that link seems to re-direct me here.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/16442/discussion-between-dmoreno-and-hesam).

Comment: Thanks for the bounty grant @Hesam! I hope you have a clearer vision of these kind of problems by the time.

Answer (score -3):

I am not sure wether this answer is correct or not, but as far as the step function is only a sign, I brought it out of the integration.

Please note that, for finding the constants, you need the boundary values and compare the value of the function at the point $x=0$.

$$\begin{array}{l}\frac{{{d^2}y}}{{d{x^2}}} - \frac{{H(x)y}}{b} = H(x)\\\frac{{{d^2}y}}{{d{x^2}}} = \frac{{H(x)y}}{b} + H(x)\\\frac{{{d^2}y}}{{d{x^2}}} = \left( {\frac{y}{b} + 1} \right)H(x)\\\frac{{{d^2}y}}{{\left( {\frac{y}{b} + 1} \right)}} = H(x){d^2}x\\\int {\frac{b}{{y + b}}{d^2}y}  = H(x)\int {{d^2}x} \\\int {\left\{ {bLn\left( {y + b} \right) + {c_1}} \right\}dy}  = H(x)\int {x + {c_3}dx} \\b\left\{ {\left( {y + b} \right)Ln\left( {y + b} \right) - \left( {y + b} \right)} \right\} + {c_1}y + {c_2} = H(x)\left\{ {\frac{1}{2}{x^2} + {c_3}x + {c_4}} \right\}\end{array}$$

Comment: The Heaviside step function is defined as $H(x) = 0$ for $x<0$ and $H(x) = 1$ for $x>1$. Also, you cannot integrate $y''/(y+b)$. Its only for expressions $y'/g(y)$ this works.

Comment: @Winther I know, but it is not type of function that change the integration too much. I mean, we can bring it out of the integration sign.

Comment: Your final solution is also not correct. To get the correct answer you need to solve two equations: one for $x>0$ and one for $x<0$ and then match them.

Comment: What's the problem with it? You could edit my answer to show to difference or problems.

Comment: There are many problems. 1) You cannot take $H(x)$ out from the integral 2) The method you use are wrong (as I tried to say: you cannot write $y'' = 1/g(y) \to \int g(y)d^2y = \int d^2x$). 3) Your final solution is not a solution to the equation.

Comment: @Winther I think that my solution is correct, I see any problem with integration the y function as above. Please post the correct answer to see the difference and let me see the correct solution.

Comment: According to your method the equation $y'' = y$ (which has solution $y = Ae^x + B e^{-x}$) can be solved as $\int\frac{d^2y}{y} = \int d^2x \to \int \ln y dy = \int x + c_1 dx \to y\ln y - y = x^2/2 + c_1x + c_2$. I hope you see this is not correct! As I tried to say above, your method makes no sense, its just wrong! (btw a correct solution has already been posted above)

Comment: @Winther Two people may solve an ODE in different ways and find different solution forms, but the core answer to be correct. As you see, I have the logarithm function in the left side which is parallel to that exponential function. $Ln(y)=x$ and $y=e^x$; what is the difference?

Comment: @Enthusiastic Student: $\int f(y)\ d^2y=F(y)\ dy$ is wrong, as the first expression is not a total differential.

Comment: No, there is only one solution to the equation (given by two free parmeters in this case).

Comment: @Winther there are many ways to find a solution. The solution is unique only after simplifications and looking for the boundary conditions.

Comment: I have tried to tell about you the many mistakes you have made and if you don't want to listen and just stick with 'I'm right' then thats OK, I'm done arguing. The downvotes you get should tell you something.

Comment: I am not insisting that I am right (just see the first line of my answer), but still I do not get why the solution is incorrect. Yes, the classic solution to the ODE is making the characteristic equation and going trough solving that homogeneous equation. Just stating that your answer is wrong, does not seem to be a good reasoning method. I think, @YvesDaoust is pointing to the wrong part, but I will be thankful to him/her to give me more reasons why it is wrong.

Comment: @Enthusiastic Student: $d(F(y)dy)=f(y)dy^2+F(y)d^2y$.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Thank you, This comment of you really helped me. :)