# Differential Equations with Discontinuous Forcing Functions

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform

$$ y''+y'+1.25y = g(t), \quad t > 0, $$

$$y(0) = 0, \quad  y'(0) = 0 $$

$$g(t) = \left\{ \begin{array}{ll}
\sin{t}  &  0 \le t < \pi  \\ 
0        &  t \ge \pi
\end{array}\right.$$

Solve the initial value problem. Draw the graphs of the solution and of the forcing function; explain how they are related.

I am confused about what a forcing function is and how to solve it. I attempted to solve it piece wise, finding that the solution for $y'' + y' + 1.25y = \sin{t}$  is $\frac{4}{17} \sin{t} - \frac{16}{17} \cos{t}$. I got the general solution for $y'' + y' + 1.25y = 0$ as $y = ce^{-1/2t}cos(t) + ce^{-1/2t} \sin{t}$. I wasn't sure what to do next.

Was I supposed to use laplace transform instead?

Comment: Wrong type of forcing for the [tag:forcing] tag. (In the future you can read these things in the small information window that pops up when you add tags.)

Answer (score 2):

Your equation is a 2nd order, constant coefficients, non-homogenous and linear ODE. Furthermore, the non-homogenous term is a piecewise function that, since $t > 0$ splits your domain into two subdomains, $I_1 = (0,\pi)$ and $I_2 = [\pi,\infty)$. This leads you to solve the equation for each of the subdomain. For doing that, follow, for example, [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/895420/solution-of-fracd2ydx2-frachx-yb-hx) link or [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/894560/ode-d2y-dx2-y-a2-ux/894570#894570). Notice, that you will end up with two solutions, $y_1(x)$ for $x \in I_1$ and $y_2$ for $x \in I_2$ with, in addition, four (different) constants of integration. You can then put some of them as functions of the others in order to have a continous solution, provided the intial conditions in $x\in I_1$.

Notice also that the homogenous part of your equations doesn't change, so it should remain the same. Indeed, we have:

$$\mathrm{L}[y_h] = y'' +y' + \frac{5}{4} y = 0, $$ and the characteristic equation tells us that $r_{1,2} = - \frac{1}{2} \pm \mathrm{i}$ are its respective solutions. So:

$$y_h(t) = e^{-t/2} ( A\cos{t} + B \sin{t} ).$$

---

Let's see how we can deal with this problem using Laplace transform. Taking Laplace transform on both sides we arrive at:

$$Y(s)(s^2 + s+ 5/4) = \mathcal{L}_s g(t), $$ where intial conditions have been considered and the RHS is the Laplace transform of a function defined over two intervals, i.e.:

$$\mathcal{L}_s g(t) = \int^\infty_0 g(t)e^{-s t} \, \mathrm{d}t = \int^\pi_0 \sin{t}e^{-st} \, \mathrm{d}t+\int^\infty_\pi 0 \times e^{-st} \, \mathrm{d}t = \frac{1+e^{-\pi s}}{s^2+1},$$

thus, solving for $Y(s)$ and anti-Laplace-transforming both sides we get:

> $$\color{blue}{y(t) = \mathcal{L}^{-1}[Y(s)] = \mathcal{L}^{-1} \left[ \frac{1 + e^{-\pi s}}{(s^2+s+5/4)(s^2+1) }   \right] = \mathcal{L}^{-1}[G(s)].}$$

Note now that we can write $G(s)$ as follows:

$$ G(s) = \frac{1}{ (s^2+s+5/4)(s^2+1)   } + \frac{e^{-\pi s}}{(s^2+s+5/4)(s^2+1)},  $$

and, since $1/(s^2+1) = \mathcal{L}_s[\sin{t}]$ and $1/(s^2+s+5/4) = \mathcal{L}_s[e^{-t/2} \sin{t} ]$ we can write:

$$ G(s) = \underbrace{\mathcal{L}_s[\sin{t}]\mathcal{L}_s[e^{-t/2} \sin{t} ]}_{Q(s)}  \ +  \ e^{-\pi s} \mathcal{L}_s[\sin{t}]\mathcal{L}_s[e^{-t/2} \sin{t} ]. $$

Therefore, by the convolution theorem we have:

\begin{align}
 q(t)  & = \sin{t} * e^{-t/2} \sin{t} = \int^t_0 \sin{(t-\tau)} e^{ -t/2} \sin{t} \, \mathrm{d} \tau \\
  & =  \frac{8}{17} e^{-t/4} \left(\cosh(t/4) \sin{t} - 4 \cos{t} \sinh{(t/4)} \right),  
\end{align}

where Mathematica has made things easier here. Finally, using the fact that $\mathcal{L}^{-1} [F(s) e^{-a s}]=H(t-a) f(t-a), $ $a\in \mathbb{R}$, where $H$ is the Heaviside or unit step function, we finally obtain the solution as follows:

> $$\color{blue}{y(t) = q(t) + H(t-\pi) q(t-\pi)}.$$

Here is a sketch of the solution for $0 \leq t \leq 5 \pi$ obtained via Laplace transform which matches, of course, with that obtained using $\texttt{DSolve}$ with Mathematica:

[image]

we can see that, if this corresponds to a dynamical system, then it is a stable damped harmonic oscillator.

---

Cheers!

Comment: If you want me to elaborate more on the first part (the piecewise solution), just tell me.

Answer (score 0):

You already proved that the solution on $(0,\pi)$ is $$y(t)=\frac{4}{17} \sin{t} - \frac{16}{17} \cos{t}+A\mathrm e^{-t/2}\cos t + B\mathrm e^{-t/2} \sin{t},$$ for some constants $A$ and $B$. Your next step should be to determine $(A,B)$ using the initial conditions $y(0)$ and $y'(0)$.

You (nearly) already proved that the solution on $(\pi,\infty)$ is $$y(t)=C\mathrm e^{-t/2}\cos t + D\mathrm e^{-t/2} \sin{t},$$ for some constants $C$ and $D$. Your next step should be to determine $(C,D)$ using the continuity of the functions $y$ and $y'$ at $\pi$. In other words, one should have $$\lim\limits_{t\to\pi,t\lt\pi}y(t)=\lim\limits_{t\to\pi,t\gt\pi}y(t),\qquad\lim\limits_{t\to\pi,t\lt\pi}y'(t)=\lim\limits_{t\to\pi,t÷gt\pi}y'(t).$$