# Convolution and Total Response Differential Equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform

Convolution with differential equations is extremely confusing to me.

The two following questions were asked in class and we were asked to think about them. I want to work them out but I don't know how.

For both problems, express the total response of the given initial value problem using a convolution integral to represent the forced response.

1) $y'' - 3y' + 2y = cos(\alpha t)$ $y(0)=1, y'(0) = 0$

and

2) $y^{(4)} - y = g(t); y(0) = 0, y'(0) = 0, y''(0) =0; y'''(0)=0$

I've tried doing the laplace transform for both problems and I just can't get the answer to look like the solutions given.

Comment: Can't you follow the same steps I and the other user described for you in your previous answer? http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/895831/differential-equations-with-discontinuous-forcing-functions. If that's not the case, please tell me.

Comment: Please consdier giving us some feedback to the users that have answered your questions. Did you understand them? Have all your doubts about the problem been solved?

Answer (score 0):

For the case $1)$ you can use the following *trick*:

- Define $z(t) = y-y_0 $ such that $z(0) = 0$ and $z'(0) = y'_0 = 0$.
- Rewrite the problem for $z$:

  > $$ z'' - 3z' + 2 z = \cos{\alpha t} - 2 \equiv f(t), \quad z(0)=z'(0) = 0, \quad t > 0. \tag{1}$$
- Laplace-transform both sides to have:

  > $$ Z(s) = \frac{1}{s^2-3 s+2} \, \mathcal{L}_s [f[t]] = \mathcal{L}_s[q(t)]\mathcal{L}_s[f(t)]. \tag{2} $$
- Compute $q(t)$ as the inverse Laplace transform of $1/(s^2 -3s+2)$. It turns out that $q(t) = e^t(e^t-1)$. Then, we can use the convolution theorem to conclude that:

  > $$\color{blue}{ z(t) = q(t)*f(t) = \int^t_0 q(\tau)f(t-\tau) \, \mathrm{d}\tau} \tag{3}$$
- Finally, $y(t)$ is given by $y(t) = z(t)+y_0$.

The process for the second problem is identical.

Hope this helps!

---

Note that under homogenous initial conditions, $G(s) = \frac{1}{s^2-3s+2}$ is defined as the *transfer function* of the dynamical system, given that: $\frac{Z(s)}{U(s)} = G(s)$.